# Allow users to see and undo their own deletions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

[As described in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132859/197769), there is a way for users to undo deletions *they themselves* requested on their own posts. Some users may not be able to do this (because of a browser limitation, for example), so I am simply requesting that this be made easier—users should be able to see their own deleted posts *if they requested the deletion themselves.* That would allow them to simply click the `undelete` link rather than having to muck around with JavaScript.